# GCC Issues, generates different output on 2 different (but similar) systems

Tags: gcc, gcc4

I am using [Brian Gladman's](http://www.gladman.me.uk/) library for EAX encryption in one of my project.

The problem is the code works on my local development environment (Ubuntu running under virtualbox) but the same code does not work (encryption incorrect) on a system running on Amazon AWS Cloud.

I have checked the GCC version and both my local environment and on the cloud. The versions are same:

> gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro
>   4.4.4-14ubuntu5)

In what cases can this happen? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of things that could cause this. It's not just the compiler, it could be:

- the version of the C libraries in use.
- undefined behaviour (or even bugs) on the part of the encryption library.
- environment variable setting such as `PATH` or `LIBPATH` which can affect the compilation/linking processes.

I don't present that as an exhaustive list. The number of possibilities is actually quite large.

You would probably have to debug it on the target environment to see exactly why it's not functioning as expected.